# How fixed "No precompiled XAML found for '/Styles.xaml' "

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I am working on C# based avaloniaui project and I need to move my style changes to a separate file so I create a Style file in the root level file name "Styles.axaml"

```
 <Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Design.PreviewWith>
            <Border Padding="20">
                <!--  Add Controls for Previewer Here  -->
            </Border>
        </Design.PreviewWith>
    
        <!--  Add Styles Here  -->
        <Style Selector="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Styles>
```

this is app.axml code

```
<Application
    x:Class="RDO.UI.App"
    xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:RDO.UI">
    <Application.DataTemplates>
        <local:ViewLocator />
    </Application.DataTemplates>

    <Application.Styles>
        <FluentTheme Mode="Light" />
        <StyleInclude Source="/Styles.axaml" />
    </Application.Styles>
</Application>
```

also, I right-clicked on the "Styles.axaml" file and went to the properties and changed the build action to "Avalonian resources"

but still, I am getting this error
Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.XamlLoadException: 'No precompiled XAML found for /Styles.xaml (baseUri: avares://RDO.UI/App.axaml), make sure to specify x:Class and include your XAML file as AvaloniaResource

this is my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <BuiltInComInteropSupport>true</BuiltInComInteropSupport>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
    <AvaloniaResource Include="Assets\**" />
    <AvaloniaXaml Remove="Styles.axaml" />
    <None Remove=".gitignore" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Styles.axaml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootDescriptor Include="Roots.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Avalonia" Version="0.10.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Avalonia.Controls.DataGrid" Version="0.10.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Avalonia.Desktop" Version="0.10.18" />
    <!--Condition below is needed to remove Avalonia.Diagnostics package from build output in Release configuration.-->
    <PackageReference Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" Include="Avalonia.Diagnostics" Version="0.10.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Splat.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="14.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="XamlNameReferenceGenerator" Version="1.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should move your `Styles.axaml` file to a separate folder (let's call it `Styles`) and include this directory as `AvaloniaResource` not `EmbeddedResource`

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AvaloniaResource Include="Assets\**" />
  <AvaloniaResource Include="Styles\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

All files in those directories will be included and the csproj will be less cluttered